# Saving Array as Image in cv2

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to modify an image using python cv2. So I imported an image to python and represent it as an array. Then I change the Red channel of the image to all 0, then I save the changed array to an image. Here I found the problem, when I load the changed image, the Red channel of the changed image isn't all 0 (but it has to be all 0 right? because the process I already did). I am so confused. Did I do anything wrong?

Here is the code:

```
im = cv2.imread("original.jpg",1)

[h,w,c] = im.shape
//print(im[:,:,0])

img2 = im.copy()

for i in range(0,h):
    for j in range(0,w):
        img2[i,j,0] = 0

cv2.imwrite("changed.jpg", img2)
```

Here is the original red channel

```
[[ 41  17  40 ...  61  82 104]
 [ 48  31  27 ...  76  51  38]
 [ 61  58  29 ...  57  53 109]
 ...
 [123 140 147 ...  95  88  74]
 [133 160 155 ...  85  83  89]
 [ 96  78  84 ...  43  47  38]]
```

And this is the changed red channel (It has to be all 0, but it doesnt)

```
[[ 9  0 10 ...  0  9 30]
 [10  0  0 ...  7  0  0]
 [15 14  0 ...  0  0 19]
 ...
 [ 0  1  5 ... 13  4  0]
 [ 9 31 21 ... 13 12 15]
 [ 0  0  0 ...  0  0  0]]
```

Comment: OpenCV `imread`/`imwrite` use BGR order -- you're modifying the red channel, not the blue one.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of issues that need to be resolved in the code:

- In Python the comments start with `#` as opposed to `//` in the attached snippet.
- Using nested for loops to iterate over the image is the slowest approach we can take. Try looking for numpy methods which do the same job instead of using nested for loops. The numpy routines are much much faster in most of the cases.
- OpenCV follows BGR convention instead of RGB convention. So to access the red channel you need to get the 3rd element in the color array not the 1st.

After fixing the issues your code may look like:

```
im = cv2.imread("original.jpg",1)

im[:,:,2] = 0

cv2.imwrite("changed.jpg", im)
```

Comment: Okay thank you, I didn't know the BGR convention, but it doesn't mean anything right(?) Because I changed (for example) the 0th channel, and then I look at also the 0th channel in the changed image.

Comment: Can you make sure that you are reading the `changed.jpg` image while you are inspecting the channel. Can you try out my code and inspect the channel before `cv2.imwrite()` ?

Comment: yes, I inspect the channel before saving it, and its true (its all 0), but if I saved it, and I inspect it later, it changes. And Im sure Im reading the `changed.jpg`. Do you think it has something to do with the array type or something?

Comment: So the problem is with the `.jpg` format here. Its a loosy format, so it may corrupt the underlying pixel values to save some Kbs while compression. You could use `.png` format which is a lossless format.